# What is the difference between this two blocks of code from the memory-consuption point of view

Tags: c#, memory-management

I am creating some objects that I send forward as parameters. Someone told me that is better to use the second block of code because is not consuming as much memory as my block of code.
What is the difference between them ?

```
object[] methodParameters = new object[] {
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "port", parameters["port"] }, { "message", Settings.RELAY_1_2_OFF_OFF } },
    null,
    null
};
//...some code...
methodParameters = new object[] {
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "port", parameters["port"] }, { "message", Settings.RELAY_3_4_OFF_OFF } },
    null,
    null
};
```

And this one.

```
object[] methodParameters = new object[3];
methodParameters[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "port", parameters["port"] }, { "message", Settings.RELAY_1_2_OFF_OFF } };
methodParameters[1] = null;
methodParameters[2] = null;
//...some code..
methodParameters[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "port", parameters["port"] }, { "message", Settings.RELAY_3_4_OFF_OFF } };
methodParameters[1] = null;
methodParameters[2] = null;
```

Comment: Is memory usage an actual issue in your program? If so, is *this* the location of the memory usage issues? Don't learn various rules of thumb and then blindly apply them because they're "better".

Comment: Or to put it another way, instead of trying to learn various "best" ways of doing things, you ought to write *clear*, understandable code that does the correct job. Then *profile* the application and, if the memory usage is unacceptable, concentrate your efforts on the actual areas where memory usage is a problem.

Comment: In the first block of code, i've tried to compact the code as much as i could. But i've got an warning that i should use the code from the second line of code.

Comment: In the first code, you create two arrays and assign them in methodParameters variable. The second code creates only one array, but you changes the content of the list in the last part.

Comment: As with so many things, it's a trade off. In the second variant, it's easy to omit assigning a new value to one of the parameters and thus accidentally send an incorrect parameter, left over from a previous usage. That's why I'd favour clearer code.

Comment: what i'm really interested in is what's happening behind the curtains, how this objects allocates memory, and if is a difference on how I initialize them.

Comment: in your first block you create new instance of array first and seconds time you set value to array. in your second block you have the same instance of array. so there is no memory leak.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is a good practice to set these kinds of variables inline (only if they are short) like I did in the first variant or it's better to use the second variant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block, the first instantiation will occupy a place in memory.  The second instantiation will occupy a different place in memory and eventually the first instantiation will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

In the second code block, there is only one instantiation of the array and the elements of the array are overwritten.

In both blocks, the Dictionary, instantiated for index 0, will occupy a place in memory then when the "new" Dictionary is instantiated it will occupy a different place in memory and eventually the first instantiation of the Dictionary will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

I would say that the first code block will "temporarily" occupy more memory until the garbage collector fires.

Comment: Thanks for clarifing things up. This is what I wanted to hear. Thanks ! Your answer helped me to understand better what's happening with memory in these two states.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine how easily the second code block could have been written as:

```
object[] methodParameters = new object[3];
methodParameters[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "port", parameters["port"] }, { "message", Settings.RELAY_1_2_OFF_OFF } };
methodParameters[1] = null;
methodParameters[2] = null;
//...some code..
methodParameters[1] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "port", parameters["port"] }, { "message", Settings.RELAY_3_4_OFF_OFF } };
methodParameters[1] = null;
methodParameters[2] = null;
```

It looks very similar to the original and yet it contains a nasty lurking bug - we end up with `methodParameters` effectively containing the same data as it did before `//...some code..`. So we've traded away clear, readable code for the sake of a single array allocation, completely ignoring that we still have the same number of `Dictionary` allocations, and that those dictionaries may have any number of internal allocations also.

So as I've said, write *clear*, understandable code, and then *profile* your code to find out where there's a *benefit* to consider reducing memory usage - and make sure you do it in ways that don't easily introduce opportunities for bugs.

I almost guarantee it's not to be found here.

Comment: Thanks for all the answer you've given ! I'l try to be more organized with the way I write my code.